# Universal app with splitView and Tab bar for iPad & iPhone in iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I have to create a universal application with  Split View type for iPad and Tab bar based for iPhone as initial root view controllers in iOS 8 using Objective-C. As these are two different root view controllers and i think size classes also won't help here.

Can any one help how to create these two type of root view controllers(iPhone & iPad) with single storyboard in iOS8.

Thanks.

Comment: You can do it by code, and i don't thing its possible in design time.

Comment: Thanks @Jageen, That makes sense and i got it with Code but i was figuring whether Xcode 6 is able to provide any options from interface builder.